# Asymptotic complexity of an algorithm (Big - O)

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, complexity-theory

I've got the following example:

```
i=2;
while i<=n {
   O(1)
   j=2*i
   while j<=n {
       O(1)
       j=j+i
   }
   i=i+1
```

I'm a beginner at calculating asymptotic complexity. I think it is O((n-1)*(n/4)) but I'm not sure if this answer is correct or I'm missing something.

Comment: This question seems difficult for a beginner.

Comment: @YvesDaoust how come?

Comment: @DarkCat It is beneficial to reduce complexities to the simplest forms possible. In the case of your proposed O((n-1)*(n/4)), this is the same as O(n^2/4-n/4) and since the quadratic term dominates the linear term and constants can be discarded, you can write O(n^2).

Comment: @YvesDaoust trying it is pointless at this moment because you have already posted a solution as an answer to this post. However, bounding a series of n/i terms for i in the range of [1,n] by nlogn is a common trick in algorithmics.

Comment: @Maurycyt: 1) there is a three steps process: -a getting the right formula for the inner loop, -b approximating by Harmonic numbers, -c using the asymptotic formula. 2) Beginners are beginners; they are not deemed to be familiar with "common trick in algorithmics". They are more likely to block at 1a. 3) the OP did fail.

Answer (score 2):

In the inner loop, `j` goes from `2i` to `n` in steps `i`, so the inner loop runs `(n-2i)/i+1` times, which is `n/i-1` (integer division).

Then the outer loop runs with `i` from `2` to `n`, for a total of `n/2-1+n/3-1+n/4-1+...n/(n/2)-1` inner iterations (for larger `i`, there are no iterations).

This quantity is difficult to estimate, but is bounded above by `n (H(n/2)-1)-n/2` where `H` denotes an Harmonic Number.

We know that `Hn~O(log n)`, hence, asymptotically, the running time is `O(n log n)`.

Comment: For the curious, the "difficult to estimate" quantity can by bounded by O(log n) in the following manner: we can bound the sum of n/2 - 1 + ... + n/(n-2) - 1 by removing the "-1" terms, at which point we receive n/2 + ... + n/(n-2) which is lesser than n + n/2 + ... + n/n, which is equal to n*H_n. One can bound H_n by O(log n) with the classic and elementary proof written down [here by Clyde Kruskal](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2016/cmsc351-0101/harmonic.pdf). This proof lacks details for n+1 not being powers of two, but that is easy to fill in.

Comment: @Maurycyt: getting an estimate is harder. Is it even Ω(log n) ?

Comment: Yes, and so are you, by saying "but is bounded above by". This is exactly what the Big-O notation is about. If one wanted a more precise estimate, they would ask for a Big-Theta estimate, which bounds from above and below.

Comment: I haven't stated anything that could require proof. I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry, no it isn't. Before you edited your reply it said something along the lines of "You are giving an upper bound, not an estimate." That is what I was replying to.